# Unsupported Operation at ServerSocket.bind using HttpServer in Flutter

Tags: sockets, flutter, dart, server, httpserver

Inconsistent behavior of HttpServer in Flutter/Dart ! The following code runs fine if executed as a desktop application but returns an error as Unsupported Operation at ServerSocket.bind if executed as a web server or through browser !

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main()
{
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home(),));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String statusText = "Start Server";

  startServer()
  async{
    setState(() {
    statusText = "Starting server on Port : 8088";
  });

  print("Attempting bind");

// other attempts with same result
//  var server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 8088, shared: true);
//  var server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 8089, shared: true);
//    var server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 0, shared: true);
//    var server = await HttpServer.bind("0.0.0.0", 35568, shared: true);

    var serverSocket = await ServerSocket.bind("0.0.0.0", 0);
    var server = HttpServer.listenOn(serverSocket);


  setState(() {
    statusText = "Server running on IP : "+server.address.toString()+" On Port : "+server.port.toString();
  });

  print("Server running on IP : "+server.address.toString()+" On Port : "+server.port.toString());

  await for (var request in server) {
    setState(() {
      statusText = request.requestedUri.toString();
    });


    request.response.headers.contentType = new ContentType("text", "plain", charset: "utf-8");
    request.response.write("hello world");
    request.response.close();

    print("Response served\n");
  }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (){startServer();},
                child: Text(statusText),)],),));
  }
}
```

- Testing on
  Ubuntu 16.04 lts
- Tested with and without firewall
- Need this to host a web service
- Any other methods available within Flutter are welcome
- Haven't yet tried with threading

Comment: `dart:io` is not supported in web browsers "**Important**: Browser-based applications can't use this library. Only servers, command-line scripts, and Flutter mobile apps can import and use dart:io.": https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/dart-io-library.html

Comment: facing the same issue with web server !

Comment: I am not sure `flutter` will work on your web server. Is it the same error? How do you execute your program on the server?

Comment: flutter run -d web-server

Comment: And can you add the full stacktrace you get?

Comment: with the web-server it shows everything's running fine, but the output never arrives, the stacktrace comes with the chrome deployment but there we have established that package fails. The UI behaves similarly for both browser and web-server executions.

Comment: Again, I don't think you can expect this code to work on a headless server where the GUI cannot be drawn (how would you touch the button which starts the server?). You code are also kinda nasty since you should not create the SocketServer as part of a GUI building. Any reason why you want to use the same Flutter code on you server instead of just creating a simple Dart implementation?

Comment: Also, please upload a complete example which can replicate your issue. You current code contains syntax errors and are missing some methods.

Comment: Any other way to host a web service ? Code seemed complete while pasting !#! Tried sockets since HttpServer.bind was giving same errors. Gotta try something else.

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/julemand101/eb1a646a1bc1484dd9286b03d6aca720

Comment: You can execute that code with `dart simple_server.dart` (don't know if `dart` is part of your PATH).

Comment: running smooth !

Comment: possible that widgets were interfering ?

Comment: I have no Flutter experience but it is properly never a good idea to import GUI frameworks into your headless server (your HTTP server was only started if you click on a bottom but how do you click on that on a headless server?).

Answer (score 4):

First, `dart:io` are not supported in web browsers so that explain your problem with running the code in browsers:

> **Important**: Browser-based applications can't use this library. Only servers, command-line scripts, and Flutter mobile apps can import and use dart:io.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/dart-io-library.html

Second, your code is very complicated if the purpose is to create a simple HTTP server running on a headless server. I have simplified your code so it does no longer depend on Flutter and can just be executed with `dart`:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  startServer();
}

Future<void> startServer() async {
  print("Starting server on Port : 8088");
  print("Attempting bind");

  final server = await HttpServer.bind("0.0.0.0", 8080);
  print("Server running on IP : ${server.address} On Port : ${server.port}");

  await for (final request in server) {
    print(request.requestedUri);

    request.response
      ..headers.contentType = ContentType("text", "plain", charset: "utf-8")
      ..write("hello world");
    await request.response.flush();
    await request.response.close();

    print("Response served\n");
  }
}
```